# How to use JS Form Validator API

Tags: javascript, api, validation

I am trying to use this form validator: https://via-profit.github.io/js-form-validator/

And at the bottom there is some API functions i'd like to use but I don't understand how they are used.

So basically created a form and have a submit button like this:

```
var validator = new Validator(formHandle, function (err, res) {
    return res;
}, options);


$(".submitMyForm").click(function(event) {
    validator.validate();
});
```

So I want to run the validator myself on click of the submit button but I know that that validate() function isn't how it works. Can someone explain how this API is used? There are no examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(".submitMyForm").click(function(event) {
    new Validator(document.querySelector('.submitMyForm'), function (err, res) {
        return res;
    });
});
```

The res is a boolean and is always present
 If the form has a validation error, the argument err will be the Object, and if there are no errors - null.

In addition to this your input fields must have a **data-rule** attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="email" data-rule="required|email"/>
```

The vertical bar (**|**) is used the use multiple rules. The list of rules can be found the docs page of api

I have not tried the code so let me know what happens